# error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment. Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Tags: ssh, gtk, ubuntu-14.04, sudo, xdgutils

I used to open text files with sublime, and for Read-only files, I used to do :
`sudo sublime`. But now just suddenly the `sudo sublime` command gives the following error :

```
(sublime:3931): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

while `sublime` command is working fine. I tried the same with `gedit`, and the same thing happened, with the error with gedit being shown :

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
(gedit:3933): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I installed `gtk`, and tried `gksudo`, still got the same error!

I searched the web and found these ways :

1. `xhost +localhost` : https://askubuntu.com/questions/614387/gksu-gtk-warning-cannot-open-display-0
2. `export DISPLAY=:0.0` :
3. `ssh username@hostname -X`
4. `ssh username@hostname -Y`
5. https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi

None of the above worked.

**What worked out for me was :**

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY sublime
```

From here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/456689/error-xdg-runtime-dir-not-set-in-the-environment-when-attempting-to-run-naut

I want to know why exactly am I getting this error, that too suddenly! Also, I want to get back to the `sudo sublime` version, since it is easy to remember. How can I fix that?

Also, the recent changes I did to the system were :

1. Installed Mac theme for Ubuntu : http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/macbuntu-1404-pack-is-released.html
2. Installed gksu(for gksudo)

Help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem.

The reason in my situation is that `sudo` does NOT inherit environment variables: `DISPLAY XAUTHORITY`.

#### HOW TO  FIX?

For Ubuntu 14, open `sudoers` file via `sudo visudo`, then paste:

```
Defaults        env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORITY"
```

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem. My fault that i followed another answer and changed file `sudoers` with next string:

```
Defaults        env_keep="https_proxy"
```

But i should have added that:

```
Defaults        env_keep += "https_proxy"
```

First string overrides existing list.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04. It was caused while following another answer.
Open terminal by pressing,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

then `$ sudo visudo`

change

```
Defaults env_keep="https_proxy"
```

to

```
Defaults env_keep += "https_proxy"
```

It worked for me.

Comment: @Idan, thanks for suggesting change. How did you make that change?

Comment: There are too many answers on the same question. Too confusing. Though I upgraded to 16.04 and am not facing this anymore, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

If you see *XDG_RUNTIME_DIR* in the output of *env* as a regular user, then all you probably need to do is use the *-E* switch to preserve the environment.